# Laravel: What does $table->primary will do in creating of foreign key

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I found some migration file like in zizaco entrust does have $table->primary on their foreign key according to [document](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/migrations#indexes) it says `Add composite keys`. What does it mean and what is the effect of it.

```
Schema::create('sub_folders', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->increments('sf_id');

    $table->integer('fid')->unsigned();
    $table->foreign('fid')->references('fid')
          ->on('folders')
          ->onUpdate('cascade')
          ->onDelete('cascade');

    $table->string('sub_folder_name', 350);
    $table->string('sub_folder_display_name', 450);
    $table->text('sub_folder_description');
    $table->integer('content_count')->unsigned();
    $table->timestamps();

    $table->primary(['fid']);
});
```